# Field Extensions, Subfield

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a subfield of a field $K$ and let $t \in K$

Let $t$ be algebraic of degree $n>1$ over $F$. Prove that $[K:F] \ge n$

Clearly there exists a polynomial $P(x)$ such that $P(t)=a_0+a_1t+a_2t^2+\dots+a_nt^n=0$, but I'm not sure how to show the dimension of $K$ as a vector space over $F$ is $\ge n$.

Comment: What's >/= supposed to mean?

Comment: I guess it is greater than or equal to....

Comment: The `/` baffles me.

Comment: "im not sure how to show the dimension of K as a vector space over F is n".. If this is really true then you could actually say $[K:F]=n$ which is not always true.. So, do not try to prove "dimension of K as a vector space over F is n"

Answer (score 2):

*Hint:* If $t\in K$ is algebraic of degree $n$ over $F$, then $1$, $t$, $t^2$, ..., $t^{n-1}$ are linearly independent over $F$.

Comment: could you please show me the next step, thanks

Comment: @cf12418, if there are $n$ linearly independent vectors in a vector space, what can you say about its dimension?

Comment: its dimension is at least n, but surely we have to show that 1,t,t^2,....,t^(n-1) spans K?

Comment: @cf12418, no, the question asks for $\dim_F K \ge n$.